# how to load an image png or jpg python3 tkinter in linux debian

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tkinter, debian

I am new to the forum, I am training on the Linux system.
I want to make an application that works well on Windows.

the problem is on "load image", i can browse, but I can't load the image.

thanks a lot

here is the code :

```py
def parcourir():
    global imageName
    imn = askopenfilename(initialdir="/",title="choisir une image",
        filetypes = (("png files","*.png"),("jpeg files","*.jpg")))
    if imn:
        imageNmae=imn
    if imageName:
        texte = imageName.split("/")
        photoEntre.confiure(text=".../"+texte[-1])
```

Comment: You didn't load the image, you just show image filename. Try [Pillow module](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: tkinter doesn't support jpg.

Comment: @acw1668 / it should show this .../ (the image path), but it doesn't show on the app, it stays as "no image selected"

Comment: Typo: `imageNmae=imn` should be `imageName=imn`.